# Define Color for specific data in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I implemented a Timeline to display my data.
To create the Timeline I used:

```
fig = px.timeline(df
                  , x_start="Start"
                  , x_end="End"
                  , y="Name"
                  , hover_name="Task"
                  , opacity=0.8
                  , template='plotly_white'
                  , height=len(df)*35
                  , width=1150
                  , color="Type"
                  , category_orders=dict(
                    Name=df["Name"].drop_duplicates().tolist()
                    )
                  )
```

You can see that the colors are based on "Type".
In my dataframe I have two types of Data: Releases and Epics.
The colors look like follows:

[image]

The problem here is that colors are generated randomly.
However, I would like to define the colors like this:

```
colors = {'Release':'rgb(255,239,0)', 'Epic':'rgb(148, 76, 228)'}
fig.update(color=colors)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried one of the `color_*` parameters of `timeline` such as `color_discrete_sequence` or `color_discrete_map`? https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.timeline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have simulated some data to fit your code
- have commented height and width so it fits on my screen
- it's a simple case of using **color_discrete_map**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

n = 8
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Start": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", freq="1M", periods=n),
        "End": pd.date_range("1-mar-2021", freq="1M", periods=n),
        "Name": [str(i) for i in range(n)],
        "Task": np.random.choice(list("ABCDE"), n),
        "Type": np.random.choice(["Epic", "Release"], n),
    }
)

fig = px.timeline(
    df,
    x_start="Start",
    x_end="End",
    y="Name",
    hover_name="Task",
    opacity=0.8,
    template="plotly_white",
    # height=len(df) * 35,
    # width=1150,
    color="Type",
    category_orders=dict(Name=df["Name"].drop_duplicates().tolist()),
    color_discrete_map={"Release": "rgb(255,239,0)", "Epic": "rgb(148, 76, 228)"},
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly fine for me! However, I needed to define color_discrete_map category_orders. Otherwise, it would just assign colors randomly again. Thank you!